# Why is this prolog code wrong?

Tags: prolog

```
not(A), not(D), not(B), not(not(D));not(not(A)), D, not(B), not(not(D));not(not(A)), not(D),B, not(not(D));not(not(A)), not

(D), not(B), not(D).
```

It reports :

> ERROR: f:/program
>   files/pl/demo/test.pl:1:
>           No permission to modify static_procedure `(;)/2'

How to make it right?

Comment: Break that single line of code into as many lines as you can without causing a syntax error. At least the error message will tell you the exact line that's causing the issue.

Comment: -1 Please read an introduction to Prolog before asking more questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

What you've given is a Prolog query that should be entered in the Prolog command prompt. It looks like you've put it into a Prolog source file, which isn't going to work. Prolog source files can only contain *facts* and *rules*.

A fact might look like this:

```
foo(bar).
```

A rule might look like this:

```
foo(X) :- baz(X).
```

The snippet you gave doesn't match either of these. In a Prolog source file, you can only string multiple conjunctions or disjunctions together in the body of a rule (ie the part to the right of the `:-` symbol).

You might want to read up on how to write prolog predicates.

Comment: You use the `;` character, this actually means disjunction. But either way, you can't have disjunctions or conjunctions inside the definition of a fact. You must define a rule and put them inside the body.

Comment: But in my case,the fact is conjunctive.Say,I know (a&^b)||(^a&b) is true.How to input such fact correctly in prolog?